# Height: 100% for textarea causes vertical scroll bar in Chrome

Tags: css, html, google-chrome, textarea

Operating system: Windows XP
Browser: Chrome 31
Issue: When I look at the following, I see an extra vertical scrollbar:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Textarea</title>
    <style>
        * {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            border: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <form>
        <textarea></textarea>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

URL: https://googledrive.com/host/0B5jOXzxlxbMhYVF3b0lubjlDWm8/textarea.html

It doesn't happen if I use `HTML 4.01 Transitional` doctype:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

What's the reason and solution?
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can fix it using `display: block;` for your `textarea` or you can use `vertical-align: top;` as well..

<s>[**Buggy Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/97rqR/)</s>

[**Fixed Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/97rqR/1/)

[**Vertically Aligned**](http://jsfiddle.net/97rqR/2/)

---

Reason: Chrome uses `display: inline-block;` for the `textarea` element which causes that issue

[image]

Comment: Really? Chrome's behaviour makes sense to me. I can't figure out how Firefox is determining the baseline of the textarea. It doesn't appear to match the description in the bug report. Any ideas?

Comment: @Alohci Well, that's how they behave, even if you add `vertical-align: top;` it will fix, I will go ahead and add that to my answer..

Comment: Yes. Chrome is setting the textarea baseline the same way as it would set an img baseline, so the usual methods for avoiding the font descender space work. But Firefox is setting the baseline differently somehow. For example, see jsfiddle.net/f353S/2/ and try tweaking the margin, padding and border width settings.

Comment: @Alohci was fiddling out with the tools and figured that out ;)

Comment: @Alohci compare this in ff and chrome http://jsfiddle.net/f353S/3/ and btw thanks for ruling the bug out...

Comment: I had chrome refusing to show vertical scroll bars at all until text area was made to be display:block. ( Version 59.0.3071.115 (Official Build) (64-bit) )  It would appear this behavior is just buggy unless display:block , as of my writing this.

Answer (score 0):

You can do multiple things:

**1:** Add `overflow: hidden` to your `*`.

```
* {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qETAD/)

**2:** Use `display: block` for the `textarea` like Mr. Alien said.

```
textarea {
    display: block;
}
```

I'd recommend this method because it's focused on the textarea element instead of all (`*`) elements in your document.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qETAD/1/)